# How to make a page with a big cytoscape.js network more responsive

Tags: javascript, html, performance, cytoscape.js

My institution is dealing with several fairly large networks:

- around 1000 nodes and 2000 edges (so smaller than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364329/scalability-of-cytoscape-js)),
- fixed node positions,
- potentially dozens of attributes per element,
- and a minified network file size of 1 MB and up.

We visualize the networks in custom-built HTML pages (one network per page) with [cytoscape.js](http://js.cytoscape.org/). The interface allows the user to select different pre-defined coloring options for the nodes (the main functionality) - colors are calculated from one of a set of numeric node attributes. Accessory functions include node qtips, finding a node and centering on it (via a select2 dropdown), and highlighting nodes based on their assignment to pre-defined groups (via another select2 drowpdown).

We face the problem that the page (and so necessarily the whole browser) becomes unresponsive for at least 5 seconds whenever a color change is initiated, and we are looking for strategies to remedy that. Here are some of the things that we have tried or are contemplating:

1. Transplant node attributes to separate files that are fetched on demand via XHRs (done, but performance impact unclear).
2. Offload cytoscape.js to a Web worker (produced errors - probably due to worker DOM restrictions - or did not improve performance).
3. Cache color hue calculation results with [lodash's memoize()](https://lodash.com/docs#memoize) or similar (pending).
4. Export each colorized network as an image and put some fixed-position HTML elements (or a canvas?) on top of the image stack for node qtips and such. So we would bascially replace cytoscape.js with static images and custom JavaScript.

I appreciate any suggestions on alternative or complementary strategies for improving performance, as well as comments on our attempts so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Changing the style for 1000 nodes and 2000 edges takes ~150ms the machine I'm using at this moment.  It follows that the issue is very likely to be in your own code.

You haven't posted an example or a sample of what you've currently written, so it's not possible for me to say what the performance issue is in your code.

You've hinted that you're using widgets like `<select>`.  I suspect you're reading from the DOM (e.g. widget state) for each element.  DOM operations (even reads) are slow.

Whatever your performance issue is, you've decided to use custom functions for styling.  The docs note this several times, but I'll reiterate here:  Custom functions can be expensive.  Using custom functions is like flying a plane without autopilot.  You can do it, but now you have to pay attention to all the little details yourself.  If you stick to the in-built stylesheets features, style application is handled for you quickly and automatically (like autopilot).

If you want to continue to use expensive custom functions, you'll have to use caching.  Lodash makes this easy.  Even if you forgo custom functions for setting `.data()` with mappers, you still may find caching with Lodash useful for your calculations.

You may find these materials useful:

- [Chrome JS profiling](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/rendering-tools/analyze-runtime?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3)
- [Firefox performance profiling](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/04/optimizing-javascript-performance-with-firefox-dev-tools/)
- [Cytoscape.js performance hints](http://js.cytoscape.org/#performance)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! We are experimenting with the indicated approaches right now, and I will post our findings once we get a clear picture of where our issues lie.

Comment: @flustered.scientist did you figure out a solution or what helped?