# Performance and layouts of Cytoscape.js

Tags: performance, cytoscape.js

I'm testing the rendering performance of Cytoscape.js.

My graph contains about 5000 nodes and 5000 edges without x, y positions, using automatic layout of Cytoscape.js. But it takes more than 15 seconds with euler layout extension after rendering all nodes and edges, the brower of the graph page will get stuck for a while or response slowly in the next operation. As it was said, the Cytoscape.js is limited by the performance of browsers. We load json data from java server client, and load datas with for loop, then use layout.run() to run auto layout. How to improve the performance with big data?

Datas with x,y positions will improve the performance, right? But we don't know how to circulate the x,y positions in Java. Can you show me? Is there java-plugin for the layouts in Cytoscape.js?

Comment: Have you tried referencing the performance section of the docs?
https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/master/documentation/md/performance.md adding some of these optimizations greatly improved my performance as well. I haven't tried 5000 nodes, so i'll definitely be following this post

Comment: yes, I had tried them. But as nodes of the graph increasing, more times will spend for layout.run(). Do you know how to 'use batches for series of operations' for big data? Noticed in:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364329/scalability-of-cytoscape-js]

Comment: the bottlenect is probably layout. Try simpler one. You can check fcose

Answer (score 4):

Cytoscape.js is impossible to be used with actual big data (i.e. terrabytes or more) because it runs in the browser. Even for medium sizes like your 5000 nodes and edges, 15 seconds sounds normal for Cytoscape.js.

The problem is that JavaScript is slower in tasks like graph layouting because modern CPUs have more and more cores and JavaScript's parallelism implementation (web workers) have too much overhead for algorithms with many short iteration steps where the result of all threads has to be integrated. Also, as far as I know, GPU computing is harder to do in JavaScript.

Both of those problems may be addressed in the future and the developer of Cytoscape.js, Max Franz, seems to be extremely active and supportive, so if JavaScript ever gets better parallelization and GPU computing support, I am positive this will find its way into Cytoscape.js shortly.

For now you could try some workarounds:

- Is the graph always the same? Then you could precalculate the layout and load it as a preset layout.
- Does the graph at least change infrequently? Then you can cache the layout and only recalculate it if necessary.

I don't know what you mean by "circulate the x,y positions in Java", do you mean "load a preset layout in the JavaScript(!) library Cytoscape.js"? If so, that is explained here: http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts/preset. Specifically, you define the x and y coordinates like:

```
let options = {
  name: 'preset',
  positions: ... // map of (node id) => (position obj); or function(node){ return somPos; }
...
```

There are also graph visualizations that have way less features than Cytoscape.js but are faster, so if you don't need any of the features and just want to visualize a simple graph, you may try [ngraph](https://github.com/anvaka/ngraph), see a demo at http://www.yasiv.com/graphs#Bai/rw5151.

Comment: Using preset layout with precalculated posiiton sounds effective but what if there's new elements which could be added every interval and need to place them based on the layout algorithm? In my thought, running the whole elements including the added one is necessary every time the new one arrives but it costs a lot.

Comment: @DongBinKim: 1. In many cases the graph will probably never change or only rarely. 2. Depending on your use case, you could just layout the new point and keep the existing ones fixed. One new point probably won't shift the other 5000 by that much anyways.

Comment: But the problem at hand is where to locate the new point(or points). The new points should be placed in the graph based on the layout algorithm I use so if I wanted to layout only the new ones, that would mean I need to understand the layout algorithm, which seems like a lot of resource.

Comment: @DongBinKim: Well you can run a layout only on a subset of elements using `eles.layout()` but this then seems to not take them into account. You could create a question / feature request in the repository for the functionality to update a layout where the original points don't change.